# How do unit testing on whether data is available oninit from activatedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

Am new to unit testing in angular . We are using jest and don't really know how to make to test whether the route is returning data or not . Am wondering can we do unit testing to check if data is return from the route in angular. Any help much appreciated

In my class component.ts

```
public data$: Observable<Data>;
  public salariesPerHours: salariesPerHoursViewModel[];

  private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.data$ = this.activatedRoute.data;
    this.data$?.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data: Data) => {
      this.salariesPerHours= data?.Salary?.salaryPerHour;
    });
  }
```

In test class compontent

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Data } from '@angular/router';
import { salariesPerHoursViewModel,SalaryType } from 'lib/store/store.barrel';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { SalaryComponent } from './salary.component';

const dataMock: salariesPerHoursViewModel[] = [
  {
      year:2018,
      salaryModifications:[
         {
            date:'2018-02-01T00:00:00',
            type: 'Salary',
            action:[
               {
                  logical :'0212834',
                  label:''
               }
            ]
         },
        ]
  }
]


describe('SalaryComponent', () => {
  let component: SalaryComponent;
  let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(() => {
    activatedRoute = new ActivatedRoute();
    component = new SalaryComponent(activatedRoute);
  });

  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit');
    });
   //how to  test if data is coming up
   
  });

  describe('ngOnDestroy', () => {
    test('should complete the destroy observable', () => {
      component['destroy$'].next = jest.fn();
      component['destroy$'].complete = jest.fn();

      component.ngOnDestroy();

      expect(component['destroy$'].next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
      expect(component['destroy$'].complete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

activatedRoute is being used inside ngOnInit, therefore the latter is not to be spied upon but to be directly tested.

Now, what are your input and output? this.activatedRoute.data is the input, this.salariesPerHours is the output.

So, before calling ngOnInit you should set your input:

```
this.activatedRoute.data = of(<mock containing Salary.salaryPerHour>);
```

And, after calling ngOnInit you should check this.salariesPerHours against expected value:

```
expect(this.salariesPerHours).toBe(<Salary.salaryPerHour from mock>);
```

It is important to observe that this.activatedRoute.data is assigned with a sync-observable ('of' operator) to allow invocation of callback (this.salariesPerHours being assigned) immediately after subscription, which makes the test controllable.

Comment: cool thank you for your response. good day